# PHP fails to connect to RabbitMQ server with AMQPStreamConnection

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm using PHP 8.1 with the php-amqplib "^3.5".

I added the code below to try the connection:

```
try {
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(....);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return FALSE;
}
```

And the following error message is always shown, even with just one connection attempt: `Too many read attempts detected in StreamIO`

I even tried to telnet from the server with error to the RabbitMQ server and it returns that the connection seems to be OK.

```
telnet 192.168.50.1 5672
Trying 192.168.50.1...
Connected to 192.168.50.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My RabbitMQ log:

```
2023-05-12 17:02:01.493761-03:00 [info] <0.7606.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.7606.4> (192.168.50.2:57988 -> 192.168.50.1:5672)
2023-05-12 17:02:04.501676-03:00 [warning] <0.7606.4> closing AMQP connection <0.7606.4> (192.168.50.2:57988 -> 192.168.50.1:5672):
2023-05-12 17:02:04.501676-03:00 [warning] <0.7606.4> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

What could possibly be happening?

**SOLVED**

The problem occurred because the ext-sockets and mbstring extensions, which are mandatory for the library, were not installed.

Comment: Given [where the error is raised](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php#L192) the error message seems a bit misleading as the code seems to imply that it's a read timeout. Please post the full stack trace.